# C code not running while using include libraries on windows

Tags: c, windows, mingw

I'm trying to run this code on visual studio code and it is not working. If I am not using anything from string.h and just print a string, it works find but once I use a method such as strtok, the file compiles but does not show anything when running and/or when running the .exe, I get an error message that it has stopped working. I have already installed the base mingw package for C.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* string = "Visual Studio Code";
    strtok(string, " ");
    printf(string);

    return 0;
}
```

This is my c_cpp_properties.json file where I include the libraries such as string.h, etc.

```
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceRoot}",
            "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include",
            "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include-fixed",
            "C:\\MinGW\\include"

    ],
```

Comment: "*libraries such as string.h*" `string.h` is not a library. Libraries are not used before linking. C is not Java. `include` is not `import`.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer `string` points to a string literal.  These are not writable, and in fact typically live in a read-only section of memory.  The `strtok` function modifies the string passed to it.  Because it is attempting to modify a string literal, you invoke undefined behavior, which in this case causes the application crashes.

You need to create an array which can be modified.

```
char string[] = "Visual Studio Code";
```

Answer (score 1):

From standard 7.24.5.8

> The strtok function then searches from there for a character that is
> contained in the current separator string. If no such character is
> found, the current token extends to the end of the string pointed to
> by s1, and subsequent searches for a token will return a null pointer.
> **If such a character is found, it is overwritten by a null character**,
> which terminates the current token. The strtok function saves a
> pointer to the following character, from which the next search for a
> token will start.

A string literal is non-modifiable and you pass it to strok which tries to modify it. This is undefined behavior. In your case you got segmentation fault.

#### Solution:

```
char string[] = "Visual Studio Code";
```

Comment: Ohhh, I feel so stupid. I didn't know I don't get error messages on windows. Thanks a lot.